# How to select which differentiable manifold to use to model spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, mathematics

I'm studying differential geometry basics for general relativity. I know that spacetime is modeled as a 4-dimensional smooth manifold. Smooth manifold means that we consider a restriction of the maximal atlas such that all charts in it are compatible. A smooth manifold is specified once we choose an equivalence class of compatible atlases. Among all coordinate charts among all of those atlases (in the equivalence class), the differentiability notion is well-defined - a curve that's differentiable in one coordinate system of one atlas will be differentiable in any other coordinate system of any other atlas in the equivalence class.

This much is clear.

I'm watching a lecture on the same topic and the lecturer discusses about an issue [here](https://youtu.be/HSyTEwS4g80?t=1350) (the link starts at the relevant timestamp and it's just a 1.5 min watch till 24:00). For the 4D case, there exist uncountably many smooth atlases up to diffeomorphism. See also [page 44 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9906167) (thanks to Chiral Anomaly for this).

At 23:25 timestamp, he mentions that the differentiability of curves depends on the atlas we're using. So a curve may be differentiable w.r.t. one atlas and not to another (not in the same equivalence class but another smooth atlas nonetheless).
So this amounts to saying that depending on the choice of smooth atlas equivalence class (which amounts to choosing what differentiable manifold to use), a curve may be differentiable in one choice and not in another.

This makes it seem that the differentiability notion is ill-defined. The lecturer talks about the same issue briefly [here as well](https://youtu.be/HSyTEwS4g80?t=3517), but doesn't get around to discussing the resolution. How is this issue resolved?

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue here - a smooth manifold is a topological manifold *together with a choice of smooth atlas*. When we do GR axiomatically and say that "spacetime is a smooth manifold", that means there's no choice left - if we used a different smooth structure on the same underlying topological manifold, that would just be a different smooth manifold.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Yes, but given several different _choices_ of atlases, you get different models of spacetime. However, some of them will say certain curves are differentiable and others won't. If all of those choices agreed on differentiability of curves, then no worries, but that probably isn't the case. How do you know which of them accurately reflects physical reality?

Comment: In what way is the differentiability of a curve a feature of "physical reality" in the first place?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: To start with, you can define a velocity along that curve. If the curve isn't differentiable at some point, then it's not even possible to define the velocity there. Also, I found this related video (starts at relevant timestamp): https://youtu.be/HSyTEwS4g80?t=1368. You can watch till the 24:00 mark. Also, at this mark: https://youtu.be/HSyTEwS4g80?t=3532, the lecturer says that the existence of multiple differentiable structures is a "real problem". Maybe I misunderstood (I probably did) and you could clarify in detail?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly: Hi, here's a video that covers this: https://youtu.be/HSyTEwS4g80?t=1350 - it's only a 1.5 min watch from 22:30 to 24:00. _At the 23:25 timestamp, the lecturer says the differentiability of a curve does depend on the atlas._ Hence the confusion. And yes, what you linked to is definitely relevant. He talks briefly about the same thing at this timestamp: https://youtu.be/HSyTEwS4g80?t=3499

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Hi, I realize my wording may have been confusing/ambiguous. I have substantially edited the question to make it much more precise and to make it clear what I'm confused about. Thanks for your feedback and I hope you find the question clearer

Comment: The standard assumption in relativity is that spacetime is locally diffeomorphic to a **standard** ${\mathbb R}^4$.  If you have some reason to want to weaken this assumption and allow exotic versions of ${\mathbb R}^4$, then the possibility that the theory is flexible enough to accommodate your needs is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @WillO: So you mean that there's only one choice of a smooth atlas equivalence class such that the manifold is locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ with standard topology? Also, could you elaborate a bit more on how weakening the assumption is a feature instead of a big?

Comment: Shirish:  Your issues seem to have nothing to do with relativity and everything to do with modeling generally.   Quantum mechanics says that the state space of a system is a Hilbert space.  **Which** Hilbert space?  It is a good feature of the theory that you can postulate different Hilbert spaces to model different situations.  Classical mechanics tells you that dynamics are dictated by the Lagrangian.  **Which** Lagrangian?  It depends on the problem you're addressing.  And in relativity, choosing the underlying manifold is just the start--- which metric do you choose?  Choices can be good.

Comment: @WillO: I've come to agree with your last comment. If it's not a hassle, I'd be really grateful if you could elaborate more, in the form of an answer so I can accept it, on the standard assumption that you were talking about in your second-last comment. You mentioned spacetime is locally diffeomorphic to a standard $\mathbb{R}^4$. Could you go into a bit more detail on that - what precisely is meant by standard, why that assumption makes sense in the context of Physics, etc.? I haven't been able to resolve this doubt from any other source, so I'd be thankful for an answer, if you get time

Answer (score 2):

I put this here since it doesnt fit in a comment. Its not an answer exactly, but I hope it may clear things up. Its pretty speculative too. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can re-affirm or deny this. And point to the right citations.

I asked a very similar question a few years ago, inspired by the same lecturer. I think the answers tend to be confusing, because different people read the question differently. I certainly didn't end up any wiser. The question posed by the lecturer is one of differentiable structure, which then effectively becomes the question from this title:

### What manifold can I use?

This is not to be confused with choices of metrics/connections, we are talking about the atlas here. When discussing what differentiable manifold to use (and only later equip with a metric) the most obvious answer is "whatever manifold you like"; you can pick one exactly as exotic as you please. This is not a helpful answer to me, because in most physics textbooks I am familiar with, a lot of calculations use a predetermined chart and deal with business locally. Making you wonder how to check if such a chart was compatible in the first place. With these sort of exercises with charts given, of course you are to presume compatibility. But what if I want to come up with my own chart, without relying on a given one?

### But what if we don't want an exotic manifold?

I am not familiar enough with the subject in order to advise on curved spaces in general and expanding universes and so on. But there is an obvious choice for a 'standard' differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}^4$ which doesn't strike me as a poor choice for flat space. For any $\mathbb{R}^d$ there is a trivial chart given by the identity on $\mathbb{R}^d$ on any open set (even globally). This satisfies any conditions you have for a $C^0$ chart: its a continuous map from the manifold into $\mathbb{R}^d$ for the right value of $d$. Thus there must be a unique maximal $C^\infty$-atlas that contains this chart. I have not seen this mentioned as 'the standard structure' anywhere, but I think it is. This is not a surprising structure for $\mathbb{R}^d$ because its equivalent to saying "I define being compatible with my altlas on $\mathbb{R}^d$ as being compatible with the notion of differentiation we already have on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (by virtue of it being a field and having a well defined subtraction and so on)."

Additionally, as far as I can tell, taking $\mathbb{R}^4$ with its standard topology and this differentiable structure still allows for curvature which is then necessarily encoded by/in the metric. This discussion is likely confused by the fact that coordinates used by physicists seem to depend on the (curvature) situation at hand. Possibly to get nice expressions of geodesics or something like that. Notice that the Lagrangian should probably depend on the curvature, but not on the coordinates used. In the end picking the 'natural' differentiable structure out of several shouldn't be shocking. We do the same thing with the topology where there is also a uncountable number of choices. The main difference seems to be that, for the case of the topology, this is well discussed.

Also notice that physicists tend to work locally. Which means its good enough when the atlas locally looks like the standard $\mathbb{R}^d$ one. In practice this strikes me as a distinction without a difference. Your predictions are the same.

Again, I want to be careful here: I am not familiar enough with the subject to be able to tell you what structure is normally picked in what case. But picking the standard one in the above sense and going with it unless you have a reason to pick something else, seems like the pragmatic move.

### Finally

From what I can piece together from the lecturer it sounds like mathematicians expected there to be a unique structure on $\mathbb{R}^4$ (up to isomorphism), before this was disproven. Perhaps this is why I have yet to find a mention of 'standard structure' in this context: people thought any structure would be equivalent, so point in explicitly picking one. Even though most people would probably use the above one when an explicit choice was needed.

I saw a similar confusing discussion on my own SE question and your related physicsformums thread. What I think is going on is the following: when this question pops up, people who are intimate with this subject might be more familiar with GR on different manifolds as well. As such they might disagree with a statement like "GR is done on standard $\mathbb{R}^4$" because it may not hold in general. They might then start arguing with the proponents of such a view who interpreted it in a more pragmatic way (what structure does one *normally* pick in the more mainstream cases?) This later group of people  is usually less sure of their answer and might be dissuaded. I am basically suggesting their answer might actually be the one you might be looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! When you say "GR on different manifolds", I'm taking different manifolds to mean spacetime endowed with different smooth atlases (not of the same equivalence class). But if it's indeed the case the GR on different manifolds is used _depending on the problem_, then aren't we steering away from a well-defined structure for spacetime? As I mentioned in the question, the choice of atlas affects the smoothness of curves (e.g. velocity), which has real physical consequences [see the 4th comment to the main question].

Comment: (cont'd) I AM aware of the fact that different metrics are used for different kinds of problems (e.g. Schwarzchild, Kerr, etc.), and that makes sense to me - since the problem dictates the distribution of matter and energy, which in turn dictates the curvature, which in turn identifies the metric to be used. BUT that is additional structure on top of the topological structure (the atlas) that we assign to spacetime. And this topological structure seems more of a modelling assumption rather than being dictated by the problem at hand. That was my takeaway from the earlier comments left by others

Comment: When I say "GR on different manifolds", I mean any differences. This includes exotic differential structure, but may in stead just be differences in topology or in the metric. Please realize that some people are doing physics in 10 dimensions. Using exotic atlasses may be like that: an interesting oddity that one might follow to see what the consequences are, rather the default strategy. But you are correct, strictly speaking the topology and atlas are part of the model.

Comment: Keep in mind though that this is not a model that you can change just because close to a black hole things look Schwarzchild-like. I dont think the atlas is part of the dynamics (so its not changing after you pick it) and it is a global choice, hence effecting your entire model of the universe all at once.

Comment: So in the end I guess the answer is that we need to enforce a particular choice of atlas equiv class on the model of the universe. Choosing a model with weaker assumptions isn't possible because in that case, we could handpick different atlases that give different results about smoothness of curves as compared to the "standard" atlas. And we don't want the description of physical reality to depend on choice of model parameters. At least that's my impression for now - I could be wrong.

Comment: To be clear, physics results will always depend on the model. Its like in Lagrangian mechanics: picking different Lagrangians will give you totally different physics. That doesnt mean Lagrangian mechanics isnt useful for describing the world. It just means an educated choice of model should be the starting point of your predictions. However, I dont think many ppl working with GR worry about the diff structure. Presumably they just use the standard structure, because it is natural and seems to give reasonable results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129030/discussion-between-fictional-and-shirish-kulhari).

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but aims to clear up some of the confusions that can happen with this problem.

There are three levels of structure that are at play here :

- an underlying *topological space* (usually $\mathbb R^4$, but in the case of a Schwarzschild BH, we need to remove the worldline of the singularity for everything to work out properly later)
- endowed with a *smooth structure*, ie an equivalence class of compatible smooth atlases.
- a *metric*, which induces a linear connection, curvature tensor, etc.

GR usually takes as an axiom "space-time is a $4$-dimensional smooth manifold", meaning that the choice of the first two structures is free.

**The issue of *exotic* 4-manifolds** : In $4$ dimension, some topological spaces can be equipped with several distinct smooth structure.  First, it is important to note that in the definition of a $4$-manifold, it is always the standard euclidean $\mathbb R^4$ which is used. Then, remains the question on whether we could do GR on an exotic $4$-manifold. In principle there is nothing preventing us from doing so, and only the physical consequences of such exotic space-times could tell if this is useful or not. This is discussed in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9212003) and [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9303035) for example.

Comment: This is a lot more concise, but I feel like this is what I was trying to get at. Would you agree with:
1 - one typically picks non exotic manifolds for the more mundane models. 2 - non-exotic means the same equivelence class as the atlas containing the identity chart?

Comment: The first paper in particular is very helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fictional : I fully agree with $1$, which is why you can probably do GR your whole life without worrying about exotic manifolds. For a manifold which is an open subset of $\mathbb R^4$, I agree with $1$ : the standard smooth structure is that inherited from that of the euclidean $\mathbb R^4$. However, there are also exotic $4$-manifolds homeomorphic to some other topological spaces (build from projective spaces and the like). In this case, the manifold comes with a natural smooth structure which stems from its construction, but may also admit other "exotic" ones.

Comment: @SolubleFish I am just trying to get clear the distinction between exotic and not. I suppose most non-exotic ones usually somehow relate to an 'Euclidean' (in the atlas sence, not the metric sense) $\mathbb{R}^d$? Like how d=4 de Sitter space is defined as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Comment: Exotic is not a rigorous term. It only applies for topological space which have a "natural" smooth structure. Any distinct smooth structure is then called "exotic". The standard smooth structures relate to open sets of euclidean $\mathbb R^4$ like any other manifolds, but I am not sure that the relation you are talking about applies to common manifolds like $\mathbb RP^4$ or $\mathbb S^4$.

Comment: Wait, you say you can construct an atlas from the topology?

Comment: No. When I say some spaces have a "natural" smooth structure, it just means that there is one obvious smooth structure, and that you have to work hard to build another one. For example, stereographic projections gives a standard smooth structure on the spheres $\mathbb S^n$. The quotient maps $\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{RP}^n$ induces a standard smooth structure on the projective spaces. If some of those spaces admits other smooth structure, they will be called "exotic"

Comment: @SolubleFish Ah, sorry I misinterpreted your previous comment. When I said "I suppose most non-exotic ones usually somehow relate to an 'Euclidean' [space]", I meant by its manifold definition (eg de Sitter space being a submanifold of Minkovski space). The charts mapping open sets into $\mathbb{R}^d$ is trivial by definition. I don't know enough about projective spaces yet, but the sphere is also usually a submanifold of an euclidean one, right?

Comment: True, but in that sense *any* manifold is a submanifold of some euclidean $\mathbb R^d$, including the exotic ones.

Comment: @SolubeFish Really? With a smooth embedding (eg inheriting your atlas by restricting charts)?

Comment: Look up Whitney embedding theorem

Comment: @SolubleFish interesting. That does throw a wrench into my idea there. I presume de Sitter coordinates still define a unique embedding though. So such an approach is clearly sometimes used. I will resist the urge to ask any more questions about specific atlasses that dont contribute to the original question. Thank you for correcting me here.

Answer (score 1):

From a physics point of view, the answer is "whichever combination of manifold, atlas, and connection is simplest but adequate to make sense of experimental data". By "simplest" here one means "simplest to human minds and discussions among a community of people".

When we do General Relativity we do not start by setting out the most general definition of what a manifold could possibly be. Rather, we give some cursory attention to that and then just jump in with some reasonably general idea and hope that it will do the job. The job being to make sense of experimental data and to make an intellectually satisfying whole.

Comment: Then how do you realize you shouldn't be using coordinates like ($\sqrt[3]{t}$,x,y,z)?

Comment: @Fictional You might not realize at first. Then you discover some singular behaviour and one of the first questions you ask yourself is whether it is owing to a poor choice of coordinates. As far as I know there is not a general prescription which always leads you to "good" or "better" coordinates, but a good thing to try is to find formulae for geodesics in whichever coordinates you started with, and then pick coordinates based on them, such that some of the geodesics have simple formulae.

Comment: But such an approach makes the definition of differentiation ill defined. I dont think its crazy to wonder 'how could I do better?' even if you wont in practice. I think physisists are so used to coordinates like (t,x,y,z) as a starting point, that they dont see this as an assumption (you are presuming these coordinates are compatible at least locally). That doesnt make the assumption 'not there'.

Comment: @Fictional I agree it is not crazy to seek an approach less liable to leave something ill-defined. I also agree it is valuable (and often difficult) to spot what has been unwittingly assumed. So my intention is not to suggest that the question is not a good one. I just want to say that what often goes on in physics is a balance between intelligent guess and experimental test which might never get fully dissected into what has or has not been assumed from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: Some of it may not "fully dissect", but I'm not convinced none of it does. I think answers exists, even if not in all cases.